# Why do some UI elements change styles, while others don't?

Tags: java, android

Today I tried to change the color of the button by adding a gradient, stroke and rounded corners.
(Done in a Drawable Resource File)

I almost succeeded, the corners were rounded, but the button color remained standard (purple_500).

I tried to solve this problem in different ways, but it didn't work out, then I tried using these styles for other elements, and they changed their color

The question is why did they change the color and the button didn't?

Code with styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="180dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@color/white"/>
            <gradient android:angle="360" android:startColor="@color/black" android:endColor="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

activity code:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="62dp"
android:layout_height="46dp"
android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
android:background="@drawable/abc"
android:text="TextView"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
android:layout_width="210dp"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
android:background="@drawable/abc"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:text="Name"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="226dp"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
android:background="@drawable/abc"
android:text="Button"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Screen with result:

[image]

I was trying to figure out how the button knows its color, of course it takes it from color.xml , but its change did not lead to the desired result, since a gradient is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton" instead of Button.

```
    android:background="@drawable/abc"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
```